# How to populate Map in Drools ResponseObject

Tags: hashmap, drools, rules

I have an object defined in .drl :

package drools.types

```
declare  ResponsibilityManager 
    @propertyReactive
    internal : java.lang.Long
    attr1 : java.lang.String  
    band : java.lang.Long
    resourceMap : java.util.HashMap

end
```

My Rule is also defined in DRL :

package drools.rules

```
import drools.types.*

rule "Third Test Rule"
    dialect "mvel"
    salience 0
    no-loop true

 when
   $var : ResponsibilityManager( band > 4  )
 then
     modify($var) { attr1 = "hidden";}
     modify($var) { getResourceMap().put("action","edit");}
end
```

Rule is getting compiled correctly, however when I execute the Rule from my Java application I am getting "NullPointerException" in that line :

```
modify($var) { getResourceMap().put("action","edit");}
```

I am able to update and return "attr1" property.

How do I update the Map in the Rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, clearly the `resourceMap` was never instantiated.

When you create the ResponsibilityManager, you need to make sure to create the resourceMap inside of it as well.

```
rule "Whatever creates the ResponsibilityManager instance"
when
  // ...
then
  ResponsibilityManager r = new ResponsibilityManager();
  r.setResourceMap(new HashMap());
  // set other fields
  insert(r);
end
```

Then you can modify it normally without getting a null pointer.

Alternatively you could overwrite the value entirely, something like ...

```
rule "Example with overwrite"
when
  $var: ResponsibilityManager( band > 4, $resources: resourceMap != null )
then
  $resources.put("new value", "example");
  modify($var) {
    setAttr1("hidden"),
    setResourceMap($resources)
  }
end
```

(Of course you'll need to make sure your resourceMap is instantiated already because of that null-check.)

Comment: Thank you! I was able to instantiate a Map, populate it and return to the client